# How to Play Corresponding Sound in LazyColumn in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-mediaplayer, android-jetpack

How to play the corresponding sound in LazyColumn in Jetpack Compose?  Like when clicked a play a sound, when clicked b play b sound. I don't want to initialize every sound manually.

```
val characters = listOf(
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    "d",
)

@Composable
fun MyUi() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    LazyColumn(){
        items(characters.size){ index ->  
            Button(onClick = {
                MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.characters[index]).start()
            }) {
                Text(text = characters[index])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `SoundPool.Builder().setMaxStreams(1).build()`, play using `play(...)`, release via `DisposableEffect`.